# Which axioms fails for this ordered pairs to be a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, abelian-groups

Let V be the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers. Is V a vector space over the Real in the case below ?
The rules for vector addition and scalar multiplication are shown below.

(a,b)+(c,d) = (a,b)

k(a,b)= (ka,kb)

I have checked all the conditions for a group but I don't know if it is commutative or not. I think it isn't as.

(a,b)+(c,d)= (a,b) but (c,d)+(a,b)=(c,d).

I think it is not a vector space due to another reason too.

As (k+k')(a,b) is not equal to k(a,b)+k'(a,b).

Are both reasons true for V not being a vector space ?

Comment: What would be the inverse of the sum? (i.e -(a,b))

Comment: @helloDarkness if you add -(a,b) to -(a,b), you can get the additive identity.

Comment: So it cannot be a vector space.

Comment: @Hello Darkness, I get it now. Well 3 axioms fail in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both reasons are correct. Arguably, to be slightly more formal, you should give a precise counterexample rather than a general form of counterexample. For instance, you have that $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a, b)$ while $(c, d) + (a, b) = (c, d)$, but this isn't strictly speaking a contradiction because it might be true that $a = c$ and $b = d$ and therefore $(a, b) = (c, d)$. To be more precise, you should point out that, for example, $(1, 2) + (3, 4) \neq (3, 4) + (1, 2)$, because it is certainly true that $1 \neq 3$.

Comment: Thank you, l will improve on that.